# ¿Como emular la tecla enter en jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me gustaría poder emular la tecla enter ya que estoy generando inputs de forma dinámica, en este momento al presionar el botón agregar producto o dar enter se genera un input e incluso se puede eliminar, pero me gustaría que mi script por default genere uno de forma predeterminada al inicio, ya logré incluir antes mis inputs en document ready pero debido a que valido mi checkbox dejó de funcionar correctamente, por eso busco esta alternativa porque no encuentro como llamar la función una sola vez al inicio.

```
<script>



$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

     var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";




    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
                var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";

                 $(wrapper).children('table').append('<tr>   <td> <select required name="productos[]"><option value="">Selecciona un Producto</option>'+selectproductos+'</select><td><select required name ="unidad[]"><option value="">Selecciona una unidad</option>'+selectunidades+'</select></td><td><input type="text" class="inputancho" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="cantidad" required="required"/></td><td><input type="date"  name="fecha_de_embarque[]" required="required"/></td>  <td> <textarea  rows="2" cols="30" name="notas[]" id="notas" maxlength="255"></textarea> </td> <td>    <input type="hidden" class="checkbox_handler" name="etiquetado[]" value="No" /><input type="checkbox" name="etiquetado_ck[]" value="Si" />   </td><td><a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></<td></tr>'); //add input box




$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});

        }
  else
  {
  alert('You Reached the limits')
  }
    });

   $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
})






});



$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {

        $("#botonagregarproducto").click();

    }
});





</script>
```

Comment: la pregunta dice que quieres emular una tecla pero tu descripción dice que **en este momento al presionar el botón agregar producto o dar enter se genera un input** y que en realidad lo que quieres es generar un input por defecto. Ya no entendí la pregunta

Comment: Asi es quiero generar un input por defecto, lo cual se que logro si llamo a la funcion una sola vez en el inicio

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es generar un `input` por defecto, osea al iniciar la página, podrías hacer esto:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //Tú código
    //       ...

    //Dices que al presionar un botón, se genera un input correctamente,
    //Entonces ejecuta esto al final de lo que ejecutas cuando se carga la página
    $("#botonagregarproducto").click();
});
```

El método `ready` de `jQuery`, permite ejecutar una función cuando el sitio ya está cargado, tu actualmente ya ejecutas una función, pero si agregas `$("#botonagregarproducto").click();` como la última instrucción que se ejecuta en la función, entonces debería "emular" un clic en tu botón, y entonces se ejecutaría la función que te permite agregar un `input`, lo cual haría.

Espero y te funcione.